# How to access a child control of parent control from another child control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, parent-child, repeater

I have a repeater control to show some pictures from a specified folder. Repeater has and image and a button inside to remove that image. But the problem how to reach that image name in button click event? This is my code below:

Aspx file:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptImage" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button id="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="DELETE" OnClick="btnDelete_Click"  />
                <asp:Image ID="image" runat="server"  ImageUrl='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

CS file:

```
private void getImages(string serialNo)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + serialNo + "/"));
            List<String> images = new List<string>(filesindirectory.Count());

            foreach (string item in filesindirectory)
            {
                images.Add(String.Format("~/Images/" + serialNo + "/{0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item)));
            }

            rptImage.DataSource = images;
            rptImage.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            header.Visible = true;

        }

    }

    protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string imgUrl;
        //The url of image is all i need to delete it

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CommandName, CommandArgument and OnCommand properties of Button.

```
protected void Btn_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "BtnClick"){
        e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    }
}

<asp:Repeater ID="rptImage" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Button id="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="DELETE"  OnCommand="Btn_Click" CommandName="Btn_Click" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItem %>"  />
          <asp:Image ID="image" runat="server"  ImageUrl="<%# Container.DataItem %>" />
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: It doesn't give me anything about url or path of the image file in repeater control. Could you explain better?

Comment: Try with updated post. You should use CommandArgument property of Button.

Comment: Thank you dude, that's it! Hang the flags ;)